# Proving an integral inequality for a non-negative measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let ($X,\mathcal{A},\mu$) be a measure space and $f : X \to \mathbb{R}_+ \cup \{\infty\}$ be a non-negative measurable function. Let $\epsilon, p > 0$ and $A = \{x \in X : f(x) \geq \epsilon\}$

I'm trying to prove the inequality $$\mu(A) \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon^p} \int_X f^p \,d\mu $$

If $\mu(A)$ and $\int_X f \,d\mu$ are both $< \infty$, then $\epsilon^{p} \mathbb{1}_{A} \leq f$ and it follows immediately that $$\mu(A) \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon^{p}} \int_X f \,d\mu $$

It also must be that if $\int_X f \,d\mu < \infty$ then $A$ can't have infinite measure. But I am not sure why. Also, I can't continue the proof for $f^p$. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g=fI_A$. Then $f^{p} \geq g^{p} \geq \epsilon^{p} I_A$. This implies $\int f^{p} d\mu \geq \int \epsilon^{p} I_Ad\mu =\mu (A) \epsilon ^{p}$. Hence $\mu (A) \leq \frac  1 {\epsilon^{p}} \int f^{p}d\mu$. For this argument finiteness of the integrals is not necessary.

Comment: If $x \in A$ then $\epsilon I_A \leq f$ but not $\epsilon^{p} I_A$ since there is no requirement that $\epsilon$ and $f$ are greater than $1$. I will edit my original post.

Comment: I am not assuming that $\epsilon$ and $f$ are greater than $1$. $f\geq \epsilon$ implies $f^{p} \geq \epsilon^{p}$ whenever $p$ and $\epsilon$ are positive. @maa'our

Comment: okay, thanks. The final inequality would fail if $\mu (A)$ is infinite, but the integral is finite. Is this a possibility?

Comment: @maa'our That will never happen. I made no assumption of finiteness of measures or  intgegrals in my argument. If the integral is finite so is $\mu(A)$ automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your help!